# Unable to view camera output while using cv_bridge

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Hydro in Ubuntu 12.04 which is installed in Virtualbox. I am trying to use cv_bridge to convert my ros images to opencv images captured by Logitech C270.

Being a novice to this field, I am following the tutorial explained on this blog : [link](https://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/working-with-ros-and-opencv-draft/) .

All works fine but still I am not able to see the camera output, rather the complete output screen appears green.

Same is the case while following the ROS tutorial, given on the link : [link](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages)

Guys I am in need of help...please help me...!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206971/unable-to-view-camera-output-while-using-cv_bridge/) by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-24**:
some more or better info, like, what commands are you running to see an image? can you normaly see the image?etc. etc.

**Comment by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) on 2015-04-24**:
Firstly thanks for your reply. Yes sure.
Initially I am using the command  - roslaunch uvcCameraLaunch.launch  ... this works fine and my camera gets light up.
After that i am running the command  - rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw.. this pops up a window named /camera/image_raw

**Comment by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) on 2015-04-24**:
This window /camera/image_raw has the screen which is completely green rather than seeing the display of camera.

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-24**:
check with "rostopic list" after uvcCameraLaunch.launch which image topics also exist and try another with "rosrun image_viewer..."

else could you see with a simply webcam app a normal picture or also a green one ?

**Comment by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) on 2015-04-24**:
Yes i am able to view properly the webcam output with webcam app.
The output of rostopic list is:
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/rosout
/rosout_agg

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-24**:
the page http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera says that one should use http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera, tried that?

**Comment by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) on 2015-04-24**:
OH thank you very much for giving me an idea that there might be some issue with package. The uvc_camera package was having some problem. So i used the package usb_cam and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use package usb_cam instead of uvc_camera.

---

Originally posted by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) with karma: 26 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0